# pytorch transformer with different dimension of encoder output and decoder memory

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

The [Pytorch Transformer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html) takes in a `d_model` argument

They say [in the forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-different-feature-size-between-source-and-target-nn-transformer/139525/2?u=noam_salomonski) that

> the [transformer model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) is not based on encoder and decoder having
> different output features

That is correct, but shouldn't limit the Pytorch implementation to be more generic. Indeed, in the paper all data flows with the same dimension == `d_model`, but this shouldn't be a theoretical limitation.

**I am looking for the reason why Pytorch's transformer isn't generic in this regard, as I am sure there is a good reason**

---

### My attempt at understanding this

[Multi-Head Attention](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html) takes in `query`, `key` and `value` matrices which are of orthogonal dimensions.
To mu understanding, that fact alone should allow the transformer model to have one output size for the encoder (the size of its input, due to skip connections) and another for the decoder's input (and output due to skip connections).

Now, looking at the Multi-Head Attention layer in the decoder which takes in Q from the decoder, and K, V from the encoder. I fail to see why K, V can't be of different dimension than Q, even with the skip connection. We could just set `d_Q==d_decoder==layer_output_dim` and `d_K==d_V==encoder_output_dim`, and everything would still work, because Multi-Head Attention should be able to take care of the different embedding sizes.

**What am I missing, or, how to write a more generic transformer, without breaking Pytorch completely and writing ot all from scratch?**

[image]

Comment: You are right, there is no constrain that Q, V, K should have the same shape, actually many papers used this fact to reduce the complexity of attentions. Regarding generic implementation, this depends on the area, if you are interested in CV, then timm library is the solution.

Comment: I have the same need, did you find a solution? :)